# How to validate many model in one controller

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin, phpunit

I have created an `AdminsController` for my website  and in this controller I am using multiple model like:  `index`, `Static_page_view`, `Admin`, `Categories`, `Products`',`contact`, `User`, `Ram`.

Now I am getting a problem to validate these model expect default model(Admin).

How can I validate?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you provide a bit more information on what are you trying to achive maybe some code as well.

Comment: What is your question? What specifically is your problem? Where do you hit the road-block? What does *validate* mean when you write it in your question? Missing a validator?

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/20/validating-multiple-models-at-once/

either using saveAll() or

```
if ($this->Model1->validates() & $this->Model2->validates() & ...) {}
```

documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array

depending on what exactly you need